# What is this type of navigation called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation, terminology

I don't know if this question is off-topic, but I am going to try anyway at the risk of getting down-voted. :D

I found this [Mega-site navigation](https://codyhouse.co/demo/mega-site-navigation/index.html#0) code and what I am interested in is when you click on "Clothing" at the top, you can then click on "Beanies" on the left and the navigation menu scrolls.

What is that called? I want to look up a tutorial on how to do it so that I can duplicate it. I want to understand what is happening.

Comment: From looking at the code it looks like they're using jQuery and just toggling Primary and Secondary side navs based on what was clicked.

Comment: Ia m not sure if this post is about this exact navigation (didn't read it), but it's post from a co-founder of the mega-site you linked and he is refering to it just as 'Full Page Intro & Navigation' - https://codyhouse.co/gem/intro-page-full-width-navigation/

Comment: inspect element > look at the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They just have a bunch of `ul`'s and if it has children then it toggles to that child.

```
<ul class="cd-secondary-nav">
                <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Menu</a></li>
                <li class="see-all"><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">All Clothing</a></li>
                <li class="has-children">
                    <a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409" class="">Accessories</a>

                    <ul class="is-hidden">
                        <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Clothing</a></li>
                        <li class="see-all"><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">All Accessories</a></li>
                        <li class="has-children">
                            <a href="#0">Beanies</a>

                            <ul class="is-hidden">
                                <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Accessories</a></li>
                                <li class="see-all"><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">All Benies</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Caps &amp; Hats</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Gifts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Scarves &amp; Snoods</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has-children">
                            <a href="#0">Caps &amp; Hats</a>

                            <ul class="is-hidden">
                                <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Accessories</a></li>
                                <li class="see-all"><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">All Caps &amp; Hats</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Beanies</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Caps</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Hats</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Glasses</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Gloves</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Jewellery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Scarves</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Wallets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Watches</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="has-children">
                    <a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Bottoms</a>

                    <ul class="is-hidden">
                        <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Clothing</a></li>
                        <li class="see-all"><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">All Bottoms</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Casual Trousers</a></li>
                        <li class="has-children">
                            <a href="#0">Jeans</a>

                            <ul class="is-hidden">
                                <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Bottoms</a></li>
                                <li class="see-all"><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">All Jeans</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Ripped</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Skinny</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Slim</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Straight</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#0">Leggings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#0">Shorts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="has-children">
                    <a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Jackets</a>

                    <ul class="is-hidden">
                        <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Clothing</a></li>
                        <li class="see-all"><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">All Jackets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Blazers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Bomber jackets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Denim Jackets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Duffle Coats</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Leather Jackets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Parkas</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="has-children">
                    <a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Tops</a>

                    <ul class="is-hidden">
                        <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Clothing</a></li>
                        <li class="see-all"><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">All Tops</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Cardigans</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Coats</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Hoodies &amp; Sweatshirts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Jumpers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Polo Shirts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Shirts</a></li>
                        <li class="has-children">
                            <a href="#0">T-Shirts</a>

                            <ul class="is-hidden">
                                <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Tops</a></li>
                                <li class="see-all"><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">All T-shirts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Plain</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Print</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Striped</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Long sleeved</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=409">Vests</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

I think this is [plugin](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) is pretty similar

Comment: Nice find! Do you know what this kind of navigation is called?

Comment: @Casey I added a link to a plugin that does this in my answer

Comment: Yes, that is just what I am looking for! Thank you!